# Increasing families of expander graphs

Tags: graphs, expanders

I would like to know if there is any research dealing with the problem of constructing an increasing family of expander graphs.

The goal is to find a family of **expander graphs** $(G_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} = ((V_i,E_i ))_{i \in \mathbb{N}} $ satisfying $V_1 \subseteq V_2 \ldots \subseteq V_n$ and $E_1 \subseteq E_2 \ldots \subseteq E_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

and more idealy a family where $V_i = \{1,2 \ldots, n \}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct such a family, with $|V_{n+1}| = 2|V_n|$, using random lifts. The classical work in the area is Bilu and Linial, [Lifts, discrepancy and nearly optimal spectral gap](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Enati/PAPERS/raman_lift.pdf). There are several recent papers of Marcus, Spielman and Srivastava on the topic (Interlacing families [I](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4132) and [IV](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.08010.pdf)), which improve the bounds in the bipartite case; see also Hall, Puder and Sawin, [Ramanujan coverings of graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02335).

A related notion is *expanding expanders*, see for example Gil Cohan and Itay Cohen, [Spectral expanding expanders](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2022/154/download/).